Need Help Generating a Kaplan-Meier Curve in a Specific Aesthetic
I've been working on generating a Kaplan-Meier plot, and I would like it to look aesthetically similar to this figure:

Currently, I have this:

**Here is the corresponding code:
**
df$time <- ifelse(!is.na(df$reinterv_Date), 
                  as.numeric(difftime(df$reinterv_Date, df$DOS, units = "days")), 
                  as.numeric(difftime(df$followup_aorta, df$DOS, units = "days")))

df$status <- ifelse(df$Distal_failure == 1 & !is.na(df$reinterv_Date), 1, 0)

df$status[is.na(df$reinterv_Date) & is.na(df$followup_aorta)] <- 0

df_below <- df[df$length_distal_lz < 4, ]
df_above <- df[df$length_distal_lz >= 4, ]

km_fit_below <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df_below)
km_fit_above <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df_above)

km_fit_below$status <- df_below$status
km_fit_above$status <- df_above$status

num_risk <- length(seq(0,5,1))
risk_below <- numeric(num_time_points)
risk_above <- numeric(num_time_points)


for (i in 1:num_risk) {
  time_threshold <- (i - 1) * 2 * 365
  risk_below[i] = sum(km_fit_below$time >= time_threshold & km_fit_below$status == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
  risk_above[i] <- sum(km_fit_above$time >= time_threshold & km_fit_above$status == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
}

risk_below[1]=35
risk_above[1]=61

risk_below_df <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 5, 1), at_risk = risk_below)
risk_above_df <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 5, 1), at_risk = risk_above)


ci_km_below <- summary(km_fit_below)$conf.int
ci_km_above <- summary(km_fit_above)$conf.int

logrank_test <- survdiff(Surv(time, status) ~ length_distal_lz >= 4, data = df)
p_value <- round(1-pchisq(logrank_test$chisq,df=1), digits=4)

km_data_below <-
  data.frame(time = km_fit_below$time, surv = km_fit_below$surv)
km_data_above <-
  data.frame(time = km_fit_above$time, surv = km_fit_above$surv)

se_km_below=km_fit_below$std.err
se_km_above=km_fit_above$std.err

km_data_below_ci <- data.frame(
  time = km_fit_below$time,
  surv = km_fit_below$surv,
  upper = pmin(1, km_fit_below$surv + 1.96 * se_km_below),
  lower = pmax(0, km_fit_below$surv - 1.96 * se_km_below)
)

km_data_above_ci <- data.frame(
  time = km_fit_above$time,
  surv = km_fit_above$surv,
  upper = pmin(1, km_fit_above$surv + 1.96 * se_km_above),
  lower = pmax(0, km_fit_above$surv - 1.96 * se_km_above)
)


ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data = km_data_below_ci,
              aes(x = time / 365, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
              fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_ribbon(data = km_data_above_ci,
              aes(x = time / 365, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
              fill = "red", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_step(data = km_data_below,
            aes(x = time / 365, y = surv, color = "LZ Length < 4 cm"),
            size = 1.5) +
  geom_step(data = km_data_above,
            aes(x = time / 365, y = surv, color = "LZ Length >= 4 cm"),
            size = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "Time (years)", y = "Survival Probability", title = "Distal Failure Free Survival by Distal LZ Length") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5, 1), limits = c(0, 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), name = "") +
  geom_text(aes(
    x = 0, y = 0.25, label = paste("log rank test", p_value), vjust = 0.1, hjust = 0.1, fontface="bold"
  )) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  geom_text(data = risk_above_df, aes(x = time, y = 0.1, label = at_risk), 
          vjust = 0, size = 4, color = "red", fontface = "bold") +
  geom_text(data = risk_below_df, aes(x = time, y = 0.0, label = at_risk), 
          vjust = 0, size = 4, color = "blue", fontface = "bold")  

Other questions I had:

how to get number at risk below the x axis and still in line with time points
currently the geom_step function is not extending one of the KM lines all the way to the upper limit of 5 years, how do I fix that

Thank you for your time in advance!
I've mainly been trying to create this plot using ggplot. I haven't tried a different function for this.
With question 1, I tried setting the y for number at risk to be negative, but then it didn't show up. I want it to be separate from the graph still and just aesthetically in line and I don't know how to do that.
With question 2, if I increase the x axis limits, it erratically extends the line, but often not right to the upper limit. I think it's how the geom_step function reads the data.

Welcome to SO, Aliya Khan! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a good start here!); sample representative data using dput(head(x)), data.frame(..), read.table(..), or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.
